# How to judge that the element is clickable or not? - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

For the [URL](https://esb.ie/tns/press-centre/2021) I'm trying to induce clicks on next page button.
To make sure that the button is clickable or not I try the following :

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fa.fa-angle-right')))
```

But this gives true for even the last page.
Where am I going wrong in my understanding?
How can I judge that a button is clickable or not anymore?
On the last page, the next page button is grayed out.

Comment: This question was asked few hours ago.

Comment: @cruisepandey that was a question related to time out error. on solving that error, the result of element_to_be_clickable is not desirable.

Comment: I could answer this, but you should show gratitude towards folks who try to help you and achieve your goal.

Comment: For your understanding, `element_to_be_clickable` == You can click it. You can click a greyed out item. It probably won't do anything, but that's why it returns true. Cruisepandey is also spot on - saying thanks goes a long way when asking for help :-)

Comment: @cruisepandey I am truly thankful for all the help I receive on this community. Thank you both :) I am simultaneously working while seeking out help. Cut me some slack! I missed it... Didn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: hmmm.. no issue, check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay attention, when the button is `getting grayed out`, it has a `class` `attribute` whose attribute value is **getting changed** to `disabled`.

You can probably make a `function` and put the below code inside that, can `call` that as per your `requirement`.

**Sample code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='next page']")))
try:
    if next_button.get_attribute('class') == "disabled":
        print('Next button is not clickable anymore')
    else:
        print('Next button is available')
        next_button.click()
except:
    print('Something went wrong')
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

`.element_to_be_clickable` can even click disabled element, so look for other ways to achieve your goals.

In the last page there are unique element, this selector:

```
a.disabled .fa.fa-angle-right
```

You can check size the element to make sure exist or not with `.find_elements_by_*` method, this will return list.

Check it out this simple loop:

```
driver.get("https://esb.ie/tns/press-centre/2021")
 
try:
    # Here I face cookie setting, accept
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
except:
    print('no cookie setting appear')
 
while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fa.fa-angle-right'))).click()
    #check last page
    if(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.disabled .fa.fa-angle-right')) > 0):
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
try:
    while True:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='next page']").get_attribute("class")=='disabled':
            print("Disabled")
            break
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='next page']").click()
        print("Clickable")
        time.sleep(5)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
Clickable
Clickable
Clickable
Disabled
```